# Openlayers - How to put street view icon on google layer?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps-api

I have a basic OL map with google layer.

http://jsfiddle.net/Alophind/bDzg7/

I've read in similiar questions that the following css disable the google street view icon:

```
img {max-width: 100%;}
```

So I added (just for case) this css into my code:

```
img {max-width: none;}
```

And I still have no google street view icon.

What else can I do ?